# Automatically load the ajax section with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a main page with ajax.Ajax section is loading at the time of select an item from drop down list.When first  i select an item from drop down list ajax updated a section,after that automatically reload the section with out select item from drop down list.How avoid the automatic reloading  again,with out selection of item?

My main page is

```
 <script>
 function sub_detail()
 {
    var exchange_rate=$('#exchange_rate').val();
    var id=$('#deposited_type').val();
    $('#sub_detail').html('<img src="images/Filling broken ring.gif" 
    style="margin-  left:411px;"> loading...');

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajx_receipt_sub_detail.php',
    data:'id='+id + '&exchange_rate=' + exchange_rate,
    success: function(msg)
    { 
       $("#sub_detail").html(msg);

       $(function() {
       $( "#slip_date2" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
    });

    //TO SET THE TIMEOUT FOR DATA TO LOAD

     setTimeout(function(){
      sub_detail();
   }, 100000);
   }
   }); 

   if(country_name!="" && cust_name!="")
   {
   //alert("kkk");
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax_country_bank2.php',
    data:'cust_name='+cust_name + '&country_name=' + country_name,
    success: function(msg)
     {
      $("#bank_list").html(msg);
     }
     });        
   }
 }
</script>
<select name="deposited_type" id="deposited_type" 
onchange="sub_detail()" <?php    if($id=="") {?>  <?php
 }?>>
<option     value="">Select</option>

<option <?php if($fet_rec['deposited_type']== 'Direct Bank Deposit')
 { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> 
 value="Direct Bank Deposit">Direct Bank   Deposit</option>
 <option <?php if($fet_rec['deposited_type']== 'CDM') { ?>
 selected="selected"     <?php      }   ?> 
 value="CDM">CDM</option>
<option <?php if($fet_rec['deposited_type']==
 'Cash Handover') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> 
 value="Cash Handover">Cash  Handover</option>

 <option <?php if($fet_rec['deposited_type']==
 'Western Union') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> 
  value="Western Union">Western   Union</option>
  <option <?php if($fet_rec['deposited_type']== 'Express Money Transfer')
  { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Express 
  Money Transfer">Express Money Transfer</option>
                 <option <?php if($fet_rec['deposited_type']== 
 'Others') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Others">Others</option>  
  </select>
```

Anybody give any help to solve these issue?

Comment: First select item from drop down with 'cdm' or other value,get updated page.After that automaticaly load again with out selection of item from drop down list.How avoid the automatic reloading  again,with out selection of item?

Comment: Why does this reload the page? If you use jQuery functions like html() or append(), then there will be no reloading. You could also trigger the functions `on Change()` of the `select` menu... Do you need to reset the `:selected` `option` on page reload?

Comment: when these value if($fet_rec['deposited_type'] is present elected option will work,with out these value not selecting,this is for edit page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function sub_detail()
 {
    var exchange_rate=$('#exchange_rate').val();
    var id=$('#deposited_type').val();
    $('#sub_detail').html('<img src="images/Filling broken ring.gif" 
    style="margin- 

 left:411px;"> loading...');
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'ajx_receipt_sub_detail.php',
data:'id='+id + '&exchange_rate=' + exchange_rate,
success: function(msg)
{ 
   $("#sub_detail").html(msg);


   $(function() {
   $( "#slip_date2" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});

  $('#exchange_rate').val(exchange_rate); //this should fix it
});
```

Comment: with out these function setTimeout(function(){
          sub_detail();
       }, 100000);
}
});  speed is very low ,so added it